# How to trigger a refreshing (reloading) of .php page when a new database entry is added?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, mysql

I have an insertUpdate.php which insert table rows into MYSQL database,

```
<?php $userid=$_POST["userid"]; $timestamp=$_POST["timestamp"]; $addALine="INSERT INTO myDatabase (userid,timestamp) VALUES ('$userid','$timestamp')";
$intoDatabase=mysql_query($addALine); ?>
```

and a showUpdate.php which show the table as a web page,

```
while ($latestRow=mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{ $data .= "<tr><td>".$latestRow[0]." </td><td> ".$latestRow[1]."</td></tr>\n";
}
```

I do not want to set an automatic refreshing every several seconds like `<?php header('Refresh: 8'); ?>`.

How to trigger a refreshing/reloading of the showUpdate.php when there is a new entry into the database inserted by the insertUpdate.php? Thanks for any help!

Comment: are you using a js library? jquery?

Answer (score 3):

Web pages are stateless. Once you send the response, it is all over.

If you want a web page to find out about a new record, it will have to poll the server to ask if there are any new records. You cannot send a notification from the server to a served-page.

Answer (score 0):

You could poll the database using AJAX(in the background) and refresh the page when a new entry is added.

Because of http being a stateless protocol there is no other option besides refreshing or polling.

Answer (score 0):

Use a XMLHttpRequest to keep page state.

```
setInterval(function(){ // every 10 seconds
    // using jQuery
    $('#container').load('/showUpdate.php'); // load php page into #container
}, 10000);
```

There are no events in a web page for when the database has changed.